Thomas Jech approach in his Theorem 4.5 proof
The 4.5 theorem:

Every perfect set in $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $|\mathbb{R}|$

Perfect set is defined to be a non-empty closed set with no isolated points. His definition of closed and open sets omitted. So, I replace with my own. An open set is any set which contains only interior points. Closed set is any set which has its complement as an open set.

His proof: Given a perfect set $P$, we want to find a one-to-one
function $F$ from $\{0, 1\}^{\omega}$ into $P$. Let $S$ be the set of
all finite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s. By induction on the length of
s $\in$ S one can find closed intervals $I_s$ such that for each n and
all s $\in$ S of length n,
(i) $I_{s}\cap P$ is perfect,
(ii) the diameter of $I_{s}\leq 1 / n$,
(iii) $I_{s^{\frown}0}\subset I_{s}$, $I_{s^{\frown}1} \subset I_{s}$ and $I_{s^{\frown}0} \cap
I_{s^{\frown}1} = \emptyset$
For each $f ∈ \{0, 1\}^{\omega}$, the set $P \cap
\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} I_{f_{|n}}$ has exactly one element, and we let
$F(f)$ to be this element of P.

Here, the meaning of $I_{s^{\frown}0}$ and $I_{s^{\frown}1}$ is to extend the sequence $s$ by adding $0$ or $1$ at the end of $s$ and evaluate $I$
I understand the whole theme of the proof: We start with a special function and then use it to construct some injection from $\{0, 1\}^{\omega}$ to $P$. Thus, $2^{\mathcal{N_0}} \leq  |P|$. But how to use induction to construct such $I_s$ and why "$P \cap \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} I_{f_{|n}}$ has exactly one element".
My attempt: If there's such function $I$ exists with $(ii)$ and $(iii)$, then the set $P \cap \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} I_{f_{|n}}$ must not have more than $2$ elements due to $(ii)$. By Cantor intersection theorem, the set is non-empty and hence contains exactly one element. Also, due to $(iii)$, such two unique points must distinct if the $f_1, f_2$ are distinct. We have proved uniqueness part.
Suggested by @Jakobian, this "proof" seems convincing for the existence part. It is trivial to build such sequence if $P$ contains some closed interval. In fact, we can just "chop" that interval infinitely to form all $I_s$ since closed intervals are perfect.
Now, let us assume that $P$ contains no closed intervals. Then, we build $I_{s^{\frown}1}$ or $I_{s^{\frown}0}$ inductively as follows: Denote $I_s = [a, b]$. Let us pick some $x_1 \in (a, b)$ with $x_1 \notin P$. This is possible since otherwise $P$ contains some closed interval.  Now, repeat this with $(a, b) - \{x_1\}$ and $(a, b) - \{x_1, x_2\}$ and $(a, b) - \{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$. We can now form $[x_1, x_2]$ and $[x_3, x_4]$ to assign to $I_{s^{\frown}1}$ or $I_{s^{\frown}0}$.  "Q.E.D"
Where does the proof goes astray? I did not even mention the word "perfect"?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I pick $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \notin P$ without realizing that $[x_1, x_2]$ and $[x_3, x_4]$ might not intersect $P$ at all. Thus, Cantor's intersection theorem possibly fails to hold. @Jakobian uses two other distinct points $x, y \in P \cap I_s$ to cover this up[this is possible since the set is perfect inductively].

In the case that $P$ does not contain any closed interval you consider $I_s = [a,b]$ and correctly argue that $(a,b)$ contains four distinct points $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ not in $P$ (and you should arrange them such that $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4$). But why are you sure that $P \cap [x_1,x_2]$ and $P \cap [x_3,x_4]$ are perfect? Couldn't they even be empty?
Here is my suggestion.
Lemma 1. Let $M \subset \mathbb R$ have no isolated points, $U \subset \mathbb R$ be an open set and $X \subset \mathbb R$ such that $U \subset X$. Then no point of $M \cap U$ is an isolated point of $M \cap X$.
Proof. Assume that $x \in  M \cap U$ is an isolated point of $M \cap X$. Then there exists an open neighborhood $V \subset \mathbb R$ of $x$ such that $(M \cap X) \cap V  =\{ x\}$. But then $W = U \cap V$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ such that $M \cap W = \{x\}$ which means that $x$ is an isolated point of $M$, a contradiction.
Lemma 2. Let $P$ be perfect, $x \in P$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a closed interval $J = [a,b]$ such that $x \in J$, $b - a < \epsilon$ and $P \cap J$ is perfect.
Proof. If there exists a closed interval $K$ such that $x \in K \subset P$, then we are done (note that all closed intervals are perfect). So let us consider the case that no closed interval $K$ with $x \in K$ is contained in $P$.
Since $x$ is no isolated point of $P$, there exists a sequence $(\xi_n)$ in $P \setminus \{x\}$  which converges to $x$. At least one of the following is true:

Infinitely many $\xi_n > x$
Infinitely many $\xi_n < x$

We only consider case 1; case 2 is treated similarly. The interval $[x,x+\epsilon/2]$ is not contained in $P$, thus there exists $y \in (x,x+\epsilon/2]$ with $y \notin P$. Let $J = [a, b]$ with $a = x, b = y$. Then $x \in J$ and $b - a < \epsilon$. Clearly $P \cap J$ is closed. We have $P \cap J = \{x\} \cup (P \cap (a,b))$. By construction, $x$ is no isolated point of $P \cap J$. By Lemma 1, no point of $P \cap (a,b)$ is an isolated point of $P \cap J$. Hence $P \cap J$ is perfect.
Now start the induction with the empty sequence $s_\emptyset$ ( with length $0$). Pick any $x \in P$ and any interval $I_{s_\emptyset}$ as in Lemma 2 (formally $1/0 = \infty$).
For the inductive step, note that $P \cap I_s$ is perfect, thus must contain two distinct points $x_1, x_2$. Let $\epsilon = \min(1/n, \lvert x_1 - x_2 \rvert/2)$ and use Lemma 2 to find the desired closed intervals.

Yes! I also figured it out minutes latter. You posted before me :-). It's like 2:23 am in my country.
